# Best way to work out if a store is open within a 24 hour period

Tags: lua, logic

Let's say I know the hour a store opens, the hour a store closes and the current hour.

```
opens = 9
closes = 21
currentHour = 4
```

I need a function something like..

```
isStoreOpen(opens, closes, currentHour) == false
```

If I do something like this..

```
currentHour >= opens and currentHour < closes
```

and the store opens at hour 1:00 and closes at 13:00 this will not work. It only works if the closes number is greater than opening.

I can imagine this has a simple solution that's been resolved before but I cannot find anything online because I'm not sure how to describe my problem properly.

Comment: Maybe ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550413/compare-dates-in-lua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your simple case, this will work:

```lua
function isStoreOpen(opens,closes,currentHour)
    if closes < opens then
        closes = closes + 24
        currentHour = currentHour + 24
    end
    return currentHour >= opens and currentHour < closes
end
```

In general, though, prefer to use libraries for time stuff.